# Menu nav bootstrap and codeigniter class active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, menu

```css
<?php 
$first_part = $this->uri->segment(1);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>e-Posiedzenie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/style.css"); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
              <div class=" col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/header.png'); ?>">
             </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-12 visible-xs">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/headerS.png'); ?>">
             </div>
      </div> 
</div>
<hr/>

<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">e-Posiedzenie</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Home") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Home'); ?>">Strona domowa</a></li>
           <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Sitting") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Sitting/4'); ?>">Nadchodzące posiedzenia</a></li>
           <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="History") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('history'); ?>">Historia z posiedzeń</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('files'); ?>">Pliki do pobrania</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <?php if($this->session->userdata('isAdmin')): ?>  
          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Panel Admina </a></li>
          <?php endif; ?>  
          <?php if($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')): ?>  
              <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('login/do_logout'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Wyloguj się </a></li> 
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')): ?> 
               <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('login'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Zaloguj się </a></li> 
          <?php endif; ?>

        </ul>
      </div>
</nav> 

</div>
```

Hi. I have template, where I have header, footer and menu, which you can see above. In this code and thanks bootstrap we can show active page "". 
Because it is template in my project I can't change just in html code in easy way as I did past. I mean, I found some way, but I don't know is it good.

The main question is whether this is a good option to start with Codeigniter and MVC? I nothing better could invent. For me this is good, but I want to learn good practice. THANKS YOU !

Comment: $first_part return Camel Case controller name?

Comment: Yes, this is name controller from url

Comment: In $first_name you will get Home in Capital?